# touch specific CCSprite among CCArray

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I having trouble in coding make movement of specific sprite among array....

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{        
    UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
    CCSprite*grade=[grades lastObject];
    [grade runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:location]];

}
```

really last object of array moving..

Can you help me to correct the code to touch specific sprite among array, and make movement of it maybe in `ccTouchesMove` method.

P.S. I use only cocos2d, not box2d.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{        
    UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

    for (CCSprite *grade in grades) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(grade.boundingBox, location)) {
            [grade runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:location]];
        }
    }   

}
```

`CGRectContainsPoint` will check if the location touched is inside the given rect. So what I did is iterate your sprites array and for sprites where the location is inside their rectangle (bounding box) than move that sprite. You can add a break inside the `if` statement if you want only the first sprite touched to be moved.