# please help touch specific sprite in array, which are dropping code

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I try to detect specific sprite with position and while i am using 'if' statement, there was failed built.

here is my codes

```
 -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch* myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];

int numGrades = [grades count]; 
for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) 
{
    // Put each spider at its designated position outside the screen 
    CCSprite* grade = [grades objectAtIndex:i];

int numGrades = [grades count]; 
for (int i = 0; i < numGrades; i++) 
{
    CCSprite* grade = [grades objectAtIndex:i];
```

// the if statement seems doesn't work...
What i try to do is if i touch specific sprite.. it should stop moving, but it does not.

```
    if ((grade.position.x==location.x) && (grade.position.y==location.y)) 
    {

        [grade stopAllAction];

    }
}
    }

 }
```

please correct 'if' statement...

Comment: possible duplicate of [touch specific CCSprite among CCArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079420/touch-specific-ccsprite-among-ccarray)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are simply trying to detect a touch on a sprite. Your current intersection test requires that your touch coordinates match exactly that of your sprite's center point, which is practically impossible..

Instead, you should try to test the touch coordinates against the bounding box of the sprite.

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(grade.boundingBox, location))     
{
    [grade stopAllActions];     
}
```

Do note too that it is stopAllActions with an "s"..

Hope this helps.